# Are "NSFetchedResultsChangeMove" and "NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate" required in didChangeSection: event for iOS 8+ NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: core-data, ios8, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm receiving this warning: "Enumeration values 'NSFetchedResultsChangeMove' and 'NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate' not handled in switch" since iOS 8.

Are these required/supported in iOS 8 for sections, or is it safe to simply provide a "default:" catch-all to remove the warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's safe to just add a `default`, according to [the documentation of NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate/controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:) the only possible values are for insert or delete:

> type: The type of change (insert or delete). Valid values are NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert and NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete.